# How to display jsoup parsed data

Tags: android, html, parsing, cordova, jsoup

I'm trying to parse from an HTML page that only has a body and in the body is a pre tag but thats it. I need to get the info from it and put it in my android app that is using phonegap. I know javascript pretty well. I heard Jsoup will work well but I'm not sure how to output the data pulled using Jsoup as text that I can display.

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: does jsoup not have any samples?

Comment: @PreetSangha Yeah it does but I don't know how to call it in my html so I can get the text and put it over an image. Thank you for the response

Comment: are u able to get a value from your html (get by jsoup) or u want the whole procedure to get a page then get some value and display them ?

Comment: @Shoshi In the html im trying to scrape from, the set up is body and in the body there is only a <pre> tag that gets updated every couple minutes with two lines of text. I want to get the information from there and display it in my android app as text over an image

Comment: @StudentOfTheGame : i have edited my answer. please check

Comment: @Shoshi as I said I'm new to this? where should I put this and how do I have it output? I'm using an android phonegap app

Comment: i am not too much familiar with phonegap. i have posted the solution in native android. u can see i have used `Thread`. because it is need for internet operation on main UI-Thread. but i think for phonegap u can used the marked portion (marked in answer) @StudentOfTheGame

Comment: @Shoshi Thank you for all your help! How do I call it in my html?

Comment: which tool are you using for development ? eclipse ? @StudentOfTheGame

Comment: sorry pal, phonegap is totally new to me. but believe me, i am working on your problem. by the way, which tool are you using for development ? eclipse ?

Comment: Yeah Eclipse but I just got it working. Thanks man @Shoshi

Comment: good to know that u got it. congratulation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this.

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element element = doc.select("input[name=username]").first();
        String get_value = element.attr("value");
        Log.e(Tag, get_value);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
    }
```

if the html is like:

```
<........
 ...........>
 <........>
<input name='username' value='fantastic' type='text' .... />
<........
 ...........>
 <........>
```

the output will be `fantastic`

**Edited**

for your case:

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
           Element element = doc.select("body").first();
           String get_value = element.text();
           Log.e(Tag, get_value);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
       }
     }
   }).start();
```

N.B: i have not run this code. but u should try this.

how to use it:

```
public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity {
    private TextView textview;
    private String get_value;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
                // marked for your use
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element element = doc.select("body").first();
                get_value = element.text();
                // marked for your use

                textview.setText(get_value);

                Log.e(Tag, get_value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
            }
          }
        }).start();

   // textview.setText(get_value);

}
}
```