# How to organize extracted values when working with jsoup?

Tags: android, json, parsing, hashmap, jsoup

How do you guys store the values extracted using jsoup in a way where it can be easily readable? So if you have an HTML code like below.

```
<td width="200">country1 </td>
<a href="http://example1.com"></a>
<td width="200">country2 </td>
<a href="http://example2.com"></a>
<td width="200">country3 </td>
<a href="http://example3.com"></a>
```

I want to save the **countries** and the **href link** for each one, and later be able to read them easily. The way I do it, I have **two ListViews** one for the countries and one for the href link.  If the user selects for example country2 I find the index of it, then use it to get the href link from the other ListView. I feel this method is not good, how do you guys do it?

This is my jsoup code by the way in case it needs more improvement too.

```
try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://somesite.com").get();

                // Here to get the names inside tag a
                Elements links = doc.select("a");
                for (Element el : links) {

                    links = el.ownText();

                    //Save all the links into String Array. 
                    array_link.add(links);
                    }

                //Here to get the names inside tag td
                Elements linktwo = doc.select("td");
                    for (Element eltwo : linktwo) {

                        linkText = eltwo.ownText();

                        //Save the countries to String Array 
                        array_countries.add(linkText);
                        }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: ... A list of objects/pairs?

Comment: Please tell me more or link me to a tutorial.

Comment: ... An object with two fields? Exposed in a list view? I think most any link view tutorial would discuss this.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not sure if I understand you. Are you referring to something called HashMap when you say objects/pairs?

Comment: you can see my answer here: [LINK][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948233/how-to-display-jsoup-parsed-data/14949182#14949182

Comment: @Shoshi your answer in the above link shows how to parse data, but I know how to do it. All I need to know is how to link country1 to www.exmaple1.com, country2 to www.example2.com and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://somesite.com").get();

                // Here to get the names inside tag a
                Elements links = doc.select("a");
                Elements linktwo = doc.select("td");
                String eltwo = null;

                int i = 0;
                for (Element el : links) {

                    eltwo = linktwo.get(i).text();

                    //Save all the links into String Array. 
                    array_link.add(el.text());
                    array_countries.add(eltwo);

                    i++;
                    }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```